# How to convert accelerometer data into G with the ADXL345 digital accelerometer

Tags: datasheet, accelerometer, conversion

Am totally new to electronics and the datasheet is very confusing to me, so can anyone please guide me through the specification of the accelerometer? So that i can have a better understanding on the accelerometer and to be able to convert the accelerometer data into G.

This is the datasheet for the ADXL345 digital accelerometer [1]: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL345.pdf

```
import smbus
import time

# Get I2C bus
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

# ADXL345 address, 0x53(83)
# Select bandwidth rate register, 0x2C(44)
#       0x0A(10)    Normal mode, Output data rate = 100 Hz
bus.write_byte_data(0x53, 0x2C, 0x0A)
# ADXL345 address, 0x53(83)
# Select power control register, 0x2D(45)
#       0x08(08)    Auto Sleep disable
bus.write_byte_data(0x53, 0x2D, 0x08)
# ADXL345 address, 0x53(83)
# Select data format register, 0x31(49)
#       0x08(08)    Self test disabled, 4-wire interface
#                   Full resolution, Range = +/-2g
bus.write_byte_data(0x53, 0x31, 0x08)

time.sleep(0.5)

# ADXL345 address, 0x53(83)
# Read data back from 0x32(50), 2 bytes
# X-Axis LSB, X-Axis MSB
data0 = bus.read_byte_data(0x53, 0x32)
data1 = bus.read_byte_data(0x53, 0x33)

# Convert the data to 10-bits
xAccl = ((data1 & 0x03) * 256) + data0
if xAccl > 511 :
    xAccl -= 1024

# ADXL345 address, 0x53(83)
# Read data back from 0x34(52), 2 bytes
# Y-Axis LSB, Y-Axis MSB
data0 = bus.read_byte_data(0x53, 0x34)
data1 = bus.read_byte_data(0x53, 0x35)

# Convert the data to 10-bits
yAccl = ((data1 & 0x03) * 256) + data0
if yAccl > 511 :
    yAccl -= 1024

# ADXL345 address, 0x53(83)
# Read data back from 0x36(54), 2 bytes
# Z-Axis LSB, Z-Axis MSB
data0 = bus.read_byte_data(0x53, 0x36)
data1 = bus.read_byte_data(0x53, 0x37)

# Convert the data to 10-bits
zAccl = ((data1 & 0x03) * 256) + data0
if zAccl > 511 :
    zAccl -= 1024

# Output data to screen
print ("Acceleration in X-Axis : %d" %xAccl)
print ("Acceleration in Y-Axis : %d" %yAccl)
print ("Acceleration in Z-Axis : %d" %zAccl)
```

These are the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to multiply the resulting acceleration measurement with the corresponding scale according to table 1 in the datasheet. The resulting value is the acceleration in `mg`.
This means if you configure the range as +-4g fullscale you would have the to multiply e.g. the x-axis by ~4.

But I guess it would be easier if you come up with a specific question or problem you're facing during implementation.

Comment: First of all,thank you for the solution you provided.
X-axis        Y-axis             Z-axis
-28              -26                 218
These are the readings i get from the accelerometer and based on the solution you provided above, do i just simply  (-28) * 4/1000 in order to get the x-axis reading in g?

Comment: That should be correct if configured as +-4g range

Comment: Until now only i have realised that the data is in +-2g but still if i just use 218*2/1000 all i get is 0.436g which is still not even close to 1g on the z-axis. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the data you get is correct? Can you show some code?

Comment: i have pasted the code in the question.

Comment: Just to be sure, can you remove the check for `zAccl > 511` and see if you really just get the 218 counts?

Comment: Sorry, the scale factor was a misinterpretation of my 5 year old code. Refering to Table 1 in the datasheet you always have 4mg/LSB on full resolution.

Comment: which means 218*0.004g = 0.872g and i right?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: But i thought when the accelerometer is stationary, the data i get from the z-axis will be 1g? Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: What do you get when you rotate it so one of the other axes sees full gravity?

Comment: Argh, i do not have access to the accelerometer right now but as soon as i get access back to the accelerometer, i'll try and roatat it and get the data from other axes.

Comment: Also note that you have up to 250mg offset on the z-axis

Comment: How can i acquire the offset value for all the axes? Do i simply put the accelerometer on a level surface?